# Why is this JS not being properly executed in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, runtime-error

This works in *all* browsers but IE. I've censored code that I *know* IE can read properly, so you're not overwhelmed. **Why does IE say that my function doesn't exist?**

**Error:**

```
SCRIPT5009: 'switchStyles' is undefined 
test.php, line 180 character 21
```

**HTML:**

```
025:    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="/_js/styleSwitch2.js"><!-- Style Switching Scripts --></SCRIPT>
...
180:    <SELECT ONCHANGE="return switchStyles(this);">
181:        <OPTION VALUE="/_css/default.css">Select a style!</OPTION>
182:        <OPTGROUP LABEL="Skin Group 1">
183:            <OPTION VALUE="/_css/alt1-1.css">Alt 1.1</OPTION>
184:            <OPTION VALUE="/_css/alt1-2.css">Alt 1.2</OPTION>
185:            <OPTION VALUE="/_css/alt1-3.css">Alt 1.3</OPTION>
186:        </OPTGROUP>
187:        <OPTGROUP LABEL="Skin Group 1">
188:            <OPTION VALUE="/_css/alt2-1.css">Alt 2.1</OPTION>
189:            <OPTION VALUE="/_css/alt2-2.css">Alt 2.2</OPTION>
190:        </OPTGROUP>
191:    </SELECT>
```

**JS:**

```
var sheetElement = document.getElementById("_switchSheet");
var backupSheetElement = document.getElementById("_switchSheetBackup");

sheetElement.disabled = false;
if (backupSheetElement)
    backupSheetElement.disabled = false;
else
    //warn

var useCookies = true;
const COOKIE_NAME = "cookiename";


function switchStyles(selectElement)
{
    if (sheetElement == null && (sheetElement = document.getElementById("_switchSheet")) == null)
        //fail
    switchStyleTo(selectElement.value);
}

function switchStyleTo(newSheet)
{
    sheetElement.href = (newSheet == backupSheetElement.href) ? null : newSheet;

    setCookie(newSheet);
}



function setUseCookies(shouldUseCookies)
{
    useCookies = shouldUseCookies;
}

function setCookie(cookieContent)
{
    //works
}

function getCookie()
{
    //works
}

function setStyleFromCookie()
{
    var cookie = getCookie();
    if (cookie.length > 0)
        switchStyleTo(cookie);
    else
        //fail
}
```

Comment: which IE are you using?

Comment: You could be calling the function before it exists.

Comment: make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please

Comment: When does the error occur? Onload or when the style is changed?

Comment: @intelis 10, 9, and 8
@Ryoku @amit_g it happens when the user interacts with the `<SELECT` element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because  this line is an error in IE, preventing the rest of the code from running.

```
const COOKIE_NAME = "cookiename";
```

change `const` to `var`.

or:

```
try {
    const COOKIE_NAME = "cookiename"; 
} catch (e) {
    var COOKIE_NAME = "cookiename";
}
```

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const): The current implementation of const is a Mozilla-specific extension and is not part of ECMAScript 5. It is supported in Firefox & Chrome (V8). As of Safari 5.1.7 and Opera 12.00, if you define a variable with const in these browsers, you can still change its value later. It is not supported in Internet Explorer 6-9, or in the preview of Internet Explorer 10. The const keyword currently declares the constant in the function scope (like variables declared with var).

Comment: changing it to var works, but the `try...catch` results int he original error. Thanks!